# Finding duplicate row pairs irrespective of column order

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a pandas data frame and I am looking for a simple way to identify rows where the values are the same (duplicate), **irrespective of the order of the columns.**

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [4, 2], [3, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [1, 3]], columns=["a", "b"])
print(df)

    a   b
0   1   3
1   4   2
2   3   1
3   2   3
4   2   4
5   1   3
```

The code should be able to identify the rows (0, 2, 5), and (1, 4) as the duplicate ones respectively.

I can't think of an efficient solution other than using a set operator to store these pairs and then finding the duplicates. Can you suggest a better method since the data frame is quite big, and thus the suggested method is very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) on `axis=1`, then `groupby`

```
u = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df,axis=1),index=df.index)
[tuple(g.index) for _,g in u[u.duplicated(keep=False)].groupby(list(u.columns))]
```

---

```
[(0, 2, 5), (1, 4)]
```

Or similarly:

```
u[u.duplicated(keep=False)].groupby(list(u.columns)).groups.values()
```

---

Outputs:

```
dict_values([Int64Index([0, 2, 5], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64')])
```